# Powershell and winapi SystemParametersInfo function

Tags: .net, powershell, winapi

I was trying this:

```
$f=@'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(
    int uAction, 
    int uParam, 
    int lpvParam, 
    int fuWinIni
);
'@

$mSpeed = Add-Type -memberDefinition $f -name "mSpeed" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru
    
$get = 0x0070
$set = 0x0071
    
$srcSpeed = $mSpeed::SystemParametersInfo($get, 0, 0, 0)
    
$newSpeed = $srcSpeed + 1
    
$mSpeed::SystemParametersInfo($set, 0, $newSpeed, 0)
```

but the mouse speed does not return. How do I write this down correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa), `pvParam` is the parameter that receives the current mouse speed, not the return value. The return value represents whether it is successful or not. It will return 0(failed) here, and then the 2nd call always sets the mouse speed to 1.

- `SPI_GETMOUSESPEED`: `pvParam` is a point to an integer.
- `SPI_SETMOUSESPEED`: It is an integer.

The equivalent C code is：

```
UINT pvParam = 0;
BOOL ret = 0;
ret = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETMOUSESPEED, 0, &pvParam, 0);
pvParam++;
ret = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 0, (LPVOID)pvParam, 0);
```

So you could declare its type as `IntPtr`：

```
$f=@'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(
    int uAction, 
    int uParam, 
    IntPtr lpvParam, 
    int fuWinIni
);
'@
```

And then create a `IntPtr` instance to receive the Integer, and read the Integer from the instance. Finally, conver the new value to a new `IntPtr` and call set method:

```
[IntPtr]$srcSpeedPtr = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::AllocHGlobal(4)

$mSpeed::SystemParametersInfo($get, 0, $srcSpeedPtr, 0)
$srcSpeed = [system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::ReadInt32($srcSpeedPtr, 0)
echo $srcSpeed

[IntPtr]$newSpeed = [IntPtr]::new($srcSpeed + 1)
$mSpeed::SystemParametersInfo($set, 0, $newSpeed, 0)

[system.runtime.interopservices.marshal]::FreeHGlobal($srcSpeedPtr)
```

Comment: Hi, @Lexxy, did this answer work for you? Please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if it did help to you.

Comment: Yes, @Drake, Thanks!

Comment: This is a great answer, which is very neat and elegant. It is really helpful to me, as well.
I really appreciate your answer.

If you let me, I'd like to ask some question, please, regarding your answer.
`IntPtr` looks like it works as a pointer in the first p/invoke function call and works as an integer value in the second call. Is that why `IntPtr` is named in such a way of `Int` + `Ptr`?

Concerning that you used `[IntPtr]::new` constructor, isn't `IntPtr` type a value type?

Comment: @SmartHumanism As you said, `IntPtr` can be a pointer, and this pointer is also an address value of type int. Its meaning depends on how the calling function use it. Here, when the function uses SPI_GETMOUSESPEED, `IntPtr` is considered as a pointer. When SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, `IntPtr` is considered as an int value