# Powershell and WinApi EnumWindows function

Tags: .net, powershell, winapi

```
$f=@'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);
);
'@

$winList = Add-Type -memberDefinition $f -name "EnumWindows" -namespace Win32Functions -passThru

$winList::EnumWindows(...)
```

How do I write this down correctly? I have do declare and pass param?
May be there is a way like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64249920/powershell-and-winapi-systemparametersinfo-function)? I'm looking for the way, where c# using just only for declaring EnumWindows function, and calling it from posh with correct params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things needed to make this work:

- Define the `EnumWindowsProc` delegate
- Make `EnumWindows()` `public` (or write a public method to wrap the call to `EnumWindows()`)

You can either implement the callback function in C# as well, or you can use a PowerShell script block.

Here's how I'd go about doing it with a script block:

```bsh
$MemberDefinition = @'
// declare the EnumWindowsProc delegate type
public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

// Notice EnumWindows() is now `public`
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);
'@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MemberDefinition -Name EnumWindowsUtil -Namespace Win32Functions

# Create a list to act as a receptacle for all the window handles we're about to enumerate
$WindowHandles = [System.Collections.Generic.List[IntPtr]]::new()

# Define the callback function
$callback = {
  param([IntPtr]$handle, [IntPtr]$param) 

  # Copy the window handle to our list
  $WindowHandles.Add($handle)

  # Continue (return $false from the callback to abort the enumeration)
  return $true
}

if([Win32Functions.EnumWindowsUtil]::EnumWindows($callback, [IntPtr]::Zero)){
  # $WindowHandles will contain all the window handles now
}
```