# Why do I see a boolean value from EnumChildWindows when using this Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, user32

A friend has a problem on his work PC.  There are frequent network issues, after which he sees dozens of error popup windows from File Explorer.  He wants a PowerShell script to close them all down without having to click each one individually.  I solved the problem in Python but he must have a PowerShell script and I'm a PowerShell novice.

I found this example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64469727/powershell-and-winapi-enumwindows-function](https://stackoverflow.com)

and I cobbled together the following script, to help me understand what I need to do.

```
function Get-ChildWindowHandles {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [IntPtr]$ParentWindowHandle
    )

    $MemberDefinition = @"
// declare the EnumChildWindowsProc delegate type
public delegate bool EnumChildWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hWnd, EnumChildWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);
"@

    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MemberDefinition -Name EnumChildWindowsUtil -Namespace Win32Functions

    # Create a list to act as a receptacle for all the window handles we're about to enumerate
    $ChildWindowHandles = [System.Collections.Generic.List[IntPtr]]::new()

    # Define the callback function
    $callback = {
        param([IntPtr]$handle, [IntPtr]$param) 

        # Copy the window handle to our list
        $ChildWindowHandles.Add($handle)

        # Continue (return $false from the callback to abort the enumeration)
        return $true
    }

    [Win32Functions.EnumChildWindowsUtil]::EnumChildWindows($ParentWindowHandle, $callback, [IntPtr]::Zero)

    return $ChildWindowHandles
}

$com_object = New-Object -com "Shell.Application"
$windows = $com_object.windows()
foreach ($w in $windows) {
    if ($w.Name -eq 'File Explorer') {
        $handles = Get-ChildWindowHandles -ParentWindowHandle $w.HWND
        foreach ($handle in $handles) {
            Write-Output "handle.GetType $($handle.GetType()) handle $($handle)"
        }
    }
}
```

It returns this:

```
handle.GetType bool handle True
handle.GetType System.IntPtr handle 591506
handle.GetType System.IntPtr handle 591192
handle.GetType System.IntPtr handle 722370
...
```

Why is the first element a boolean?  I'd be very grateful if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong.

As an aside, why aren't File Explorer windows seen when I try
`Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle} #| Select-Object MainWindowTitle`?

Thanks in advance for any help
Chris

Comment: In short: any output - be it from a PowerShell command, an operator-based expression, or a .NET method call - that is neither captured in a variable nor redirected (sent to a file or via the pipeline to another command) is _implicitly output_ from a script or function. To simply _discard_ such output, use `$null = ...`, for instance, as shown in mclayton's answer.
If you don't discard such output, it becomes part of a script or function's "return value" (stream of output objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnumChildWindows` returns a `BOOL` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows:

```
BOOL EnumChildWindows(
^^^^
  [in, optional] HWND        hWndParent,
  [in]           WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc,
  [in]           LPARAM      lParam
);
```

That return value isn't being captured in your function so it's being returned implicitly as part of the function's output stream.

You can capture it with:

```
$null = [Win32Functions.EnumChildWindowsUtil]::EnumChildWindows( ... )
^^^^^^^
```

and it'll no longer appear in the function return values.

Other options to do the same thing are:

```
[void] [Win32Functions.EnumChildWindowsUtil]::EnumChildWindows( ... )
^^^^^^
```

or

```
[Win32Functions.EnumChildWindowsUtil]::EnumChildWindows( ... ) | Out-Null
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

but `$null =`  is my own personal stylistic preference

Comment: mclayton, thanks for your help.  That worked and I've learned something about PowerShell too!